# Removing the first element from a queue?

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue

I have a queue. If it exceeds X size, when I push an element I want to remove the first element of the queue. (the last element that would get popped and the first element pushed in)

```
void ClientPlayerManager::queueTableMessage( const std::string& playerName, const std::string& message )
{
    m_tableQ.push(std::make_pair(playerName,message));

    if(m_tableQ.size() > m_maxTableMessages)
    {
        //m_tableQ.pop_back(); does not exist
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with a std queue?

Thanks

Comment: In a FIFO queue, the last element that would get popped is at the opposite end from the first element pushed in.  Which do you want?

Comment: Yes, it's quite confusing. Why not just use push and pop and forget about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `std::deque` instead of a `std::queue`, which supports `push_front`, `push_back`, `pop_front`, and `pop_back`.  This also allows for random access throughout, but you can just ignore that and treat the `deque` like a double-ended queue.  (In fact, `deque` is short for double-ended queue).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove an element from the opposite end from what `pop` does, just skip pushing it in the first place:

```
if(m_tableQ.size() < m_maxTableMessages) {
    m_tableQ.push(std::make_pair(playerName,message));
}
```

Comment: No, the idea is that I want the top X messages to stay, when I have X messages, the one of least importance (the oldest one) goes and a new one is in.

Comment: @Milo: In that case, you can just use `pop`.